# $geoWithin query fail to retrieve point included in the queried polygon

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query a document using its location with two polygons that are quite similar. Both includes the location of the document but one finds it and the other not. I thought that this was related to ["big polygons"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#std-label-geowithin-big-poly) but I managed to reduce the polygons enough to rule out this possibility. [See previous post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/ununderstood-behaviour-of-geowhitin-with-larger-polygon/213417). Any idea explaining such a difference?

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/sTEtYD3HU8m:

Document:

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63ef9379e671073bfb963145"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        2.834,
        47.264
      ]
    },
    "_class": "org.example.springdatamongodbgeowithinissue.model.SamplingGeometry"
}
```

Is not in search results for this polygon:

```
{
  "geometry": {
    "$geoWithin": {
      "$geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -16.1,
              49.12
            ],
            [
              -16.1,
              46.156
            ],
            [
              16.1,
              46.156
            ],
            [
              16.1,
              49.12
            ],
            [
              -16.1,
              49.12
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still the same issue with Earth's curvature. Your area is long enough to take it into account:

[image]

zooming in and's clearly outside:

[image]

The map: https://jsfiddle.net/blex18/w9g4bzyk/1/

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.body, {zoom:5,center:{lat:47.264,lng:2.834}});
new google.maps.Polygon({geodesic:true,map:map,geodesic:true,
    path:[
        {lat:49.12,lng:-16.1},
        {lat:46.156,lng:-16.1},
        {lat:46.156,lng:16.1},
        {lat:49.12,lng:16.1},
        {lat:49.12,lng:-16.1}]});
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat:47.264,lng:2.834},
    map,
    title: "Here",
  });
```

Comment: Good catch! Apparently this was not the issue I wanted to post but I managed to bump on it creating my example. I've created [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75487505/geowithin-query-fail-to-retrieve-point-included-in-the-queried-polygon-v2) if you could have a look! Cheers