# $geoWithin query fail to retrieve point included in the queried polygon - v2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've already ask the same question [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75485981/geowithin-query-fail-to-retrieve-point-included-in-the-queried-polygon). My example was subject to earth curvature issue so lets have a look to another one.

---

This time I have two nested polygons. A large one and a smaller one. Performing a $geoWithin query with the larger one return no document while the document is found using the smaller polygon. Any thoughts?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/V_3-s-itngA

[image]

The document I'm trying to query which is located on an island on France west coast.

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "625fec0f6476793a4581d172"
    },
    "featureOfInterest": {
      "samplingFeature": {
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -2.3433781679840138,
            46.713764788942484
          ]
        },
        "name": [
          {
            "lang": "en",
            "text": "France"
          }
        ],
        "type": "Feature"
      }
    }
  }
```

And the query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$or": [
        //Largest polygon - return no document
        {
          "samplingFeature.geometry": {
            "$geoWithin": {
              "$geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                  [[-55.722656,34.161818],[58.007813,34.161818],[ 58.007813,53.540307],[ -55.722656, 53.540307], [-55.722656,34.161818]]]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        //Smallest polygon - return the document
        //{
        //  "samplingFeature.geometry": {
        //    "$geoWithin": {
        //      "$geometry": {
        //        "type": "Polygon",
        //        "coordinates": [[[-5.800781, 42.682435], [9.316406, 42.682435], [9.316406, 50.625073], [-5.800781, 50.625073], [-5.800781, 42.682435]]]
        //      }
        //    }
        //}
        //}
        
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've bent the planet other way round. The coordinates in your post make these boxes:

[image]

the marker is clearly outside the the larger box.

Please use the link to jsfddle in my answer to your previous question instead of globes, or wherever you get your image from. The shortest path between 2 points far away does not necessarily follow longitudes and latitudes. Please read about the math of [Geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) calculations used in mongo geospatial queries.

Comment: Perfect demonstration. You pointed me the right direction to solve my issue. I realized that a geojson line is always the geodesic shortest path  according to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.1). I was using images from geojson.io. Following the rfc they also should update their projections.

Comment: Nice UI. Shame they don't support geodesic paths.